# LMMS isn't starting on raspberry pi 4b runing Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: pulseaudio, 21.04, jack, lmms

It started two or three days ago. I installed ubuntu 21.04 on my raspberry pi 4b, and installed lmms on it. It worked well enough, but one day, I tried switching from pulseaudio to jackd2 as the audio server. I turned the latency down to the lowest possible. (I would show a screenshot, but the lmms gui isn't working.) It shows the startup screen, but now it won't show the gui. Sometimes an error window pops up that says "ubuntu has an internal error", and another one says "lmms closed unexpectedly." It does not do that every time I try; sometimes it shows nothing at all. It just doen't bring up the gui. I tried launcing lmms via terminal, and these are the error logs  it produced.

```
pi@pi-raspberrypi:~$ lmms
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Notice: could not set realtime priority.
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.17
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2021 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10) (1: Operation not permitted)
AcquireSelfRealTime error
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/5) (1: Operation not permitted)
JackClient::AcquireSelfRealTime error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = lmms was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Destination port in attempted (dis)connection of system:playback_2 and  is not an input port
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
pi@pi-raspberrypi:~$ Destination port in attempted (dis)connection of system:playback_2 and  is not an input port
JackGraphManager::Disconnect: port_src = 10 not used name = 
Input port index = 10 not found for application ref = 2
Unknown error...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Jack::JackTemporaryException'
  what():
```

I reinstalled lmms a couple of different ways like using snap via terminal, snap via the snap sotre, and snap via apt terminal and it has the same problem.
Know what can be done to fix it? It seems like it has something to do with a misinstalled jack.  I tried reinstalling all jack, libjack, and jackd packages I could find, but no fix yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it!!! I purged all jack and jackd and libjackd packages; lmms now just starts with asking me to chance the audio server. I selected the audio server snd it works fine. It seems like an internal glitch that I pypassed by deleting stuff. It's not a very clean fix, and it makes little sense to me. But it fixed the problem. (it at least made lmms work if it did not fix it, but just bypassed it) It works flawlessly now and that's all that matters.